# how does Thread.sleep(delay) react to actual parallel threads

Tags: java, multithreading

[The link to the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html):  **Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period**

What does the term **current thread** mean? I mean if the processor has only one core that it makes sense to coin one of the threads as the *current thread*, but if all the threads(say 4 of them) are running individually on *separate cores*, then which one is the *current thread*?

Comment: The current thread is the one running `Thread.sleep`. But it seems as though you're implying that threads and cores have a 1/1 relationship...

Comment: It is worth saying that number of cores has barely anything to do with number of threads. Even on a single core CPU you can run multiple applications at the same time, each with its own thread or multiple threads.

Comment: "Current" as in "the one currently executing the call being documented". Sleep always operates on the current thread, you can't make another thread sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single command and method call you make has to be executed by anyone thread. From that thread's perspective, it is itself the current thread. So in other words: `Thread.sleep(delay)` pauses the thread that executes the `Thread.sleep()` method.

Also, keep in mind that multi-threading and multiple cores only have a very distant relationship.

Even before multi-core CPUs were commonplace, pretty much every operating system supported heavy multi-threading (or multi-tasking, which is basically the same thing for the purpose of this discussion) operation.

In modern OS this is done with a technique called [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking). This basically means that the OS can forcibly pause the currently running process and allow another one to run for a short time, providing the illusion of actual parallel processing.

And since a lot of time in a given process is often spent waiting for some external I/O (network, disk, ...) that even means that you can use the CPU more efficiently (since the time a process would spend waiting for IO another process can spend doing actual computation).

As an example at the time of writing this, my laptop has 1311 threads (most of which are probably sleeping and only a handful will actually run and/or wait to run), even though it has only 4 cores.

**tl;dr** while multiple cores allow more than one thread to actually execute at the exact same time, you can have multi-threading even with a single core and there's very little noticeable difference if you do (besides raw performance, obviously)

Answer (score 3):

The "current thread" is the thread which calls `Thread.sleep(delay)`.

Also if a thread sleeps, it does not block the entire CPU core. Some other thread can be run on the same CPU core while your thread is asleep.

Answer (score 1):

The name, "Current thread," was chosen for the convenience of the authors of the operating system, not for the authors of applications that have to run under the operating system.

In the source code for an operating system, it makes sense to have a variable `current_thread[cpu_id]` that points to a data structure that describes the thread that is running on that `cpu_id` at any given moment.

From the point-of-view of an application programmer, any system call that  is supposed to do something to the "current thread," is going to do it to the thread that makes the call.  If a thread that is running on CPU 3 calls `Thread.sleep(n)`, the OS will look up `current_thread[3]` (i.e., the thread that made the call) and put that thread to sleep.

From the application point-of-view, `Thread.sleep(n)` is a function that appears to *do nothing*, and always takes at least `n` milliseconds to do it.

In general, you should substitute "the caller" or "the calling thread" any time you see "current thread" in any API document.